# How to have an excel file open in PowerShell to foreground of command prompt?

Tags: excel, powershell

What I want to do is have the Excel file open in front of the command prompt when running the PowerShell script. So far, it's only opening behind the command prompt. Also, the alerts pop up behind too.

This is my code to open the Excel file in PowerShell.

```
$file = 'path'
$excl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'
$wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
$excl.DisplayAlerts = $TRUE
```

Comment: The linked duplicate is about Internet Explorer, but should work with Excel too. I've posted a self-contained Excel example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048290/45375).